# TFS - testing a common module by running builds of projects that depend on it

Tags: git, tfs

I am using:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 16.131.28507.4
```

I have a Git maven Java class library that builds in TFS and publishes to Artifactory.

I have several other projects that depend on this class library.

So when someone creates a PR against my main branch in my Git maven Java class library, I would like to have a few smoke tests from some of the other projects be a prerequisite to run prior to allowing the PR to be merged.

There is a feature in `Repository Settings -> Branches -> Protect Branch - require task to pass before PR merge`. But the problem is this job runs prior to publishing to my shared library to artifactory, and I cannot pull my new dependency.

I expected something like Jenkins has, where you can run another project's build task. But it doesn't seem to exist in TFS.

And I tried pulling out powershell and doing it via script, but when you try to git freezes.

Is there some way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected something like Jenkins has, where you can run another project's build task. But it doesn't seem to exist in TFS.

Yes, we could not run another project`s build pipeline in current PR Build validation:

[image]

But we could create a build pipeline to invoke REST API [Builds - Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Builds/Queue?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1):

```
POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1
```

to trigger another project's build pipeline, and use [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) to check the result of that pipeline.

Next, we use the [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#example-1) to set the current build result based on the triggered pipeline result.

```
##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]DONE
```

Comment: Almost worked. But the problem is, there is no way to force the "Job 1: Build and publish to antifactory" to run prior to the "Job 2: Run a smoke test of client application using the snapshot project artifact". So when Job 2 runs, Job 1 hasn't finished yet, so Job 2 fails saying "library yourlib-2.2-SNAPSHOT is not available". I will have to combine these jobs into a single pipeline, which is I suppose not a big deal.